# react context provider return undefine as component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

this the first time to me with  context in Reactjs and have this problem
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.  Check the render method of App `

FeedbackContext.js

```
import React from "react";
const defaultValue = {
    uid: null,
    title: null,
    appName: null,
    type: null,
    feedbackDescription: null,
}

 const  FeedbackContext = React.createContext({
    selectedFeedback: defaultValue,
    updateSelectedFeedback: () => {}

});

export default FeedbackContext ;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import MainNav from "./componets/Navbar/MainNav";
import firebase from './config/fbConfig';
import RoutersContainer from "./AppRouters/RoutersContainer";
import FeedbackContext from "./contextApi/FeedbackContext";

class App extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userType: 'undefined',
            selectedFeedback: {
                uid: null,
                title: null,
                appName: null,
                type: null,
                feedbackDescription: null,
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({userType: 'login'})
            } else {
                this.setState({userType: 'logout'})
            }
        })
    }

    updateSelectedFeedback = (feedback) => {
        this.setState({selectedFeedback: feedback})
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <FeedbackContext.provider value={{
                selectedFeedback: this.state.selectedFeedback,
                updateSelectedFeedback: this.updateSelectedFeedback
            }}>
                <div className="App">
                    <MainNav userType={this.state.userType}/>
                    <RoutersContainer userType={this.state.userType}/>


                    {/*this button only on test mode*/}
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        {
                            if (this.state.userType === 'admin') {
                                this.setState({userType: "login"})
                            } else if (this.state.userType === 'login') {
                                this.setState({userType: "admin"})
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                    >
                        he is {this.state.userType}
                    </button>

                </div>
            </FeedbackContext.provider>
        );

    }
}



export default App
```

ShowButton.js

```
import React from "react";
import FeedbackContext from "../../contextApi/FeedbackContext";
class ShowButton extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return (

            <FeedbackContext.consumer>
                {({updateSelectedFeedback ,selectedFeedback }) => <>
                <button onClick={updateSelectedFeedback(this.props.feedback)}>Show</button>
                    {console.log(selectedFeedback)}
                </>}
            </FeedbackContext.consumer>



        )
    }
}

export default ShowButton
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's consumer should be capital.

```js
//....
render() {
        return (

            <FeedbackContext.Consumer>
                {({updateSelectedFeedback ,selectedFeedback }) => <>
                <button onClick={updateSelectedFeedback(this.props.feedback)}>Show</button>
                    {console.log(selectedFeedback)}
                </>}
            </FeedbackContext.Consumer>



        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was  solved ... the consumer and provider should start with capital later